# Reduce Plotly.js library size

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am building a simple landing page which includes a 3d scatterplot graphic from plotly, nevertheless the minified library [weights 3MB](https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js), way too big for a mobile landing page.

In [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/41) closed feature request, they speak about modularise the library so you can choose which components to download, but there is not such an option in the download page.

Does anybody have any suggestion as to how to reduce the size of the file taking out the unnecessary components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the ReadMe in this directory https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist for information on alternative bundles. For more info on building your own bundle see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/CUSTOM_BUNDLE.md